# Spring config Import resource with exclusions

Tags: spring, import

I am using Spring to configure my application and wish to import a particular resource A. Now, resource A has another  tag in it which includes resource B. But, I wish to include resource A only by itself without its subsequent imports. Is there any way to do so?

For eg, here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
....
...
<import resource="A.xml" >
```

Here is resource A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
....
....
<import resource="B.xml" >
```

As mentioned, I need to import A.xml and exclude B.xml. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **don't** think it is possible in Spring (**as of now**).

Spring will load **all the bean definitions** found in Application-context.xml or similar file into it's container.

You can either import **all** beans from an xml or **completely ignore**. This can be achieved by using @Profile annotation.

OR You need to **split** your bean definition xmls.

Comment: I see. Then is there any way to "over-ride" the inherited XML.. For eg: if the inherited B.xml has <test Bean>, can I provide my own implementation of <test Bean> in my configuration and make it so that it refers to it instead of that from B.xml?

Comment: Just create a bean in your configuration with different bean id, say bean id ="testBean2" , then class="fully-qualified-name-of-your-own-implementation class". This way you can "ignore" <test bean> instead of "override".

Comment: Can you give me an example please, for doing so?

Comment: Nothing special, just create bean for your own implementation class and use it.